# Why CodedInputStream.readRawVarint64() is reading all the bytes from underlying stream?

Tags: java, stream, protocol-buffers

Here is a sample code demonstrating the problem.

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    CodedOutputStream cos = CodedOutputStream.newInstance(bos);
    cos.writeRawVarint64(25);
    cos.flush();
    bos.write("something else".getBytes());
    System.out.println("size(bos) = " + bos.size());  // This gives 15

    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
    CodedInputStream cis  = CodedInputStream.newInstance(bis);
    System.out.println("size(bis) = " + bis.available()); // This gives 15
    long l = cis.readRawVarint64();   
    System.out.println(cis.getTotalBytesRead()); // This gives 1, which is correct
    System.out.println("Raw varint64 = " + l);  // This gives 25, which is correct
    System.out.println("size(bis) = " + bis.available()); // This now gives 0!!
```

All I am trying to do is to encode a 64 bit integer and add some more data to the payload. I can read the encoded data correctly. But for some reason, it clears the underlying stream after that. Any one know why this is happening? How can I read the `varint` from stream and read the remaining bytes as indicated by the `varint`?

Any help would be great

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what codedinputstream does but it could very well buffer the input meaning it reads e.g. 100 bytes a time.

Either way you should not wrap an inputstream B around an inputstream A and continue reading from A specifically because you don't know what B does.

For instance maybe B must look ahead in the data to form some conclusion or it uses buffering or...

Additional note: available() is usually a bad idea though it should work correctly specifically on a bytearrayinputstream.

**EDIT**:

In conclusion: just continue reading from the codedinputstream, don't try to read from the underlying one.

Comment: This is correct.  For efficiency, CodedInputStream reads a large chunk of data from the underlying stream at a time.  You can use `CodedInputStream#readRawBytes()` to read the bytes from the `CodedInputStream`'s buffer.